# EditText in TableRow values getting mixed up

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-sqlite

I have an application that uses the `ViewPager` control with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

I have created a `TableRow` view as follows:

`item_row.axml`

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:text="Item"
      android:layout_margin="1dp"
      android:id="@+id/txtRowItemName"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:gravity="left" />
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:inputType="number" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:id="@+id/txtInventory" />
</TableRow>
```

I have a `TableLayout` in another view:

`inventory.axml`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:isScrollContainer="false"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:scrollbars="vertical">
  <TableLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tblInventory"
    android:gravity="top">
  </TableLayout>      
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the backend code for my Fragment

```
public class InventoryFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    private DataAccess database;
    private TableLayout _tblLayout;
    private ApiData _data;
    public static InventoryFragment NewInstance(ApiData data, DataAccess dbAccess)
    {
        InventoryFragment newFragment = new InventoryFragment { Arguments = new Bundle(), ApiData = data, database = dbAccess };                        
        return newFragment;
    }
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {                
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.inventory, container, false);
        _tblLayout = view.FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tblInventory);
        IList<StoreItem> storeItems = database.GetStoreItems();
        IList<InventoryCheck> inventoryValues = database.GetLastCheck();
        if(storeItems != null)
        {
            if(storeItems.Any())
            {                       
                foreach (StoreItem itm in storeItems)
                {
                    InventoryCheck lastInventory = null;
                    if (inventoryValues != null)
                        lastInventory = inventoryValues.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ItemID == itm.ID);
                    View itemRows = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_row, container, false);
                    _tblLayout.AddView(itemRows);
                    TextView txtItemName = itemRows.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtRowItemName);
                    //Setup edit text
                    EditText txtInventory = itemRows.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtInventory);  
                    txtInventory.Tag = itm.ID;              
                    //Add OnFocus Changed
                    txtInventory.FocusChange += (sender, e) => 
                    {
                        if(!e.HasFocus)
                        {
                            int value = 0;
                            int.TryParse(txtInventory.Text, out value);
                            //Saves the value to database upon loosing focus
                            database.SetInventoryItem(itm.ID, value);
                        }
                    };                  
                    txtItemName.Text = itm.ItemName;
                    txtInventory.Text = (lastInventory) != null && lastInventory.Inventory > 0 ? lastInventory.Inventory.ToString() : string.Empty;
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that, when I put text in the field, it saves it in the DB. Upon debugging, I can see that the data is being transferred just fine, but when the view loads up, the values are all messed up. It replaces all the values with the one in the last item.

When I swipe the application out of the 'Recent Items' and run it again, the values that populate their are correct. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: have you checked that when the data is showing correctly on swipe up and down does it messes up or remain same ?

Comment: @Umair When I enter the data and Swipe two pages back and return, it messes up the data. But when I quit the app and bring it back, the data is all fine

Comment: @Umair can you help with this?

Comment: I believe the problem is in your adapter view method. Do one thing attach a debugger on your method which populate the rows. And after that when your app launches fine for the first time surpass the break point then mess with your layout and see what debugger finds out.

Comment: @Umair so I did what you said. The debugger seems to get the values saved in the database when the `OnCreateView` method is called. (The method is called when the view's pager strip is loaded). But when we swipe to the actual view it only shows the values of the last row in all the items.

Comment: Can you tell me why are you using height as 0dp in scrollview ?

Comment: @Umair so that there is no predefined height and the view should be scrollable. Is that the reason why my tablelayout is being messed up :-S

Comment: yeah I believe so. Try giving it height and give table layout fixed or wrap_content height.